# how to pass Html.HiddenFor from view to view and controller mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to pass id from page to submit form but is seem like no luck.

```
    @model IList<MySiteCom.ViewModels.ReviewViewModel>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor((x => x[i].ReviewId))
    @Html.ActionLink("comment", "AddComent", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ReviewId) })

}
```

page 2

```
    @model MySiteCom.Models.Comments

@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.review.ReviewId)

@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Comment: The values won't be persisted for more than one request, you could you ViewData,ViewBag to persist data.

However if you edit your post and include what you are trying to achieve, we can probably suggest a better way.

You don't go from view to view either, you go from view to controller.

Comment: I agree , this is what I need to achieve , I have a reviews in a view page  ,and I need to post comment on any review. I hope it's clear

Comment: You need to show your controller code and what you have tried.

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to do. Is the code in your 1st snippet a view which displays all Reviews, and you want to click a link to add comment associated with a specific Review? (in which case what is the purpose of the hidden input since you do not have a form). Your link needs to be just `Html.ActionLink("comment", "AddComent", new { id = Model[i].ReviewId) })`

Comment: And then in your `AddComment(int ID)` the value of the parameter ID will be the value of the `ReviewId`. Now you can initialize your `Comments` model and set its properties - e.g. var model = new Comments{ review.ReviewId = ID, .... };` and pass that model to the view.

Comment: commnets.ReviewId = id; ;Stephen Muecke , thank you , it's always more simple then I think it is .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the hidden field value from one View to the Controller, then pass the value from Controller to the other View with the help of TempData, ViewBag or ViewData etc. You can use HiddenFor directly by the property name of the Model as shown below:

***View I:***

```
@model IList<MySiteCom.ViewModels.ReviewViewModel>

@foreach (var review in Model)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="ReviewId" value=review.ReviewId />
    @Html.ActionLink("comment", "AddComent", new { id = review.ReviewId  })
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult AddComment([Bind(Exclude = null)] ReviewViewModel review)
{   
    //...
    TempData["revId"] =  review.ReviewId;
{
```

***View II:***

```
var value = @TempData["revId"]
```

For the differences between ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData you might have a look at [When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in ASP.NET MVC 3 applications](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/).

Comment: You code cannot work because you are creating a hidden input based on a collection (it generates `name="[0].ReviewId"` but the model in the `AddComment()` method is a single object, not a collection so binding will fail and the value of `comment.ReviewId` will be its default value (`0` assuming its typeof `int`)

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work either - the model in the first view is `@model IList<MySiteCom.ViewModels.ReviewViewModel>` and `List<T>` does not have a property `ReviewId`. For more info, see my comments to the question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke As the question is not clear, I just wanted to give an example by some assumptions.

Comment: You should be not answering questions which are unclear :). You should be voting to close and/or down vote.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, I just wanted to help :) But now I did what you had suggested. Thanks...